# Check if DateTimeField contains a specific number

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a number "5".
How can I check if a `DateTimeField` value contains that number?

"25/10/15" should be true, while "20/10/12" should be false.

Answer (score 2):

Simple one line code.

```
from datetime import datetime

print ('5' in (str(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y"))))
```